# VB.net How to remove quotes characters from a streamReader.readline.split()

Tags: vb.net, replace, trim, streamreader

I had built a project that read data from a report and it used to work fine but now for some reason the report puts every thing in to strings. So I want to modify my stream reader to remove or ignore the quotes as it reads the lines.

This is a snipet of the part that reads the lines.

```
Dim RawEntList As New List(Of Array)()

Dim newline() As String
Dim CurrentAccountName As String
Dim CurrentAccount As Account
Dim AccountNameExsists As Boolean
Dim NewAccount As Account
Dim NewEntry As Entrey
Dim WrongFileErrorTrigger As String

ListOfLoadedAccountNames.Clear()
'opens the file
Try
    Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(File1Loc)
    Console.WriteLine("Loading full report please waite")
    MsgBox("Loading full report may take a while.")
    'While we have not finished reading the file
    While (Not sr.EndOfStream)
        'spliting eatch line up into an array
        newline = sr.ReadLine.Split(","c)
        'storring eatch array into a list
        RawEntList.Add(newline)
    End While
```

And then of course I iterate through the list to pull out information to populate objects like this:

```
For Each Entr In RawEntList
    CurrentAccountName = Entr(36)
    AccountNameExsists = False
    For Each AccountName In ListOfLoadedAccountNames
        If CurrentAccountName = AccountName Then
            AccountNameExsists = True
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do

```
StringName.Replace(ControlChars.Quote, "")
```

or

```
StringName.Replace(Chr(34), "")
```

OR

```
streamReader.readline.split().Replace(Chr(34), "")
```

Comment: Its not an string its an array of strings thats how split() works. and you cant call replace on an array.
I guess I could call it on evey value thats in the array like this  `ent(0).Replace(Char(34), "")` and that would have to be illtrated through 50 times. witch is already running inside of another iltration that is  running 150,000 times or more. Its posable but it is very un-efficient. So that sort of rules out your top two solutions but the third one I might try out to see if it works.

Comment: @SkylineGodzilla : So put `.Replace()` before you call `.Split()`. While the latter may return an array, `ReadLine()` doesn't: `sr.ReadLine().Replace(Chr(34), "").Split(","c)`.

Comment: @WallyModz : OR `StringName.Replace(""""c, "")`. ;)

Comment: @SkylineGodzilla You could do a foreach or just do what Visual Vincent said.

Comment: A for each loop requires more iterations, which he doesn't want. Edit your answer and give your examples the same structure as mine (`sr.ReadLine().Replace(...).Split(...)`). That way all of them will work in his situation.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing the replace before the split, after the readline? That should save iteration multiplication, or better yet (if possible), do a replace on the entire file (if the data is formatted in the way it can be done & you have enough memory) using the ReadAllText method of the File object, do your replace, then read the lines from memory to build your array (super fast!).

File.ReadAllText(path)